# CPointer in Kotlin-Multiplatform

Tags: c, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I cannot find any samples on how to get CPointer in Kotlin Multiplatform, and the documentation that exists doesn't help much. 
In my iOS source set, I need to build the Kotlin equivalent of the following Swift code (only including relevant parts of the code):

```
  ...(hex: String) {

if hex.hasPrefix("#") {
    let start = hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
         let scanner = Scanner(string: hexColor)
         var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0



          if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber) {

            r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
           ....
```

The specific part I am having problems with is

> scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber)

This is the Kotlin code and the question

```
//input to function - hex: String
    val scanner = NSScanner(hex)
    if (hex.startsWith("#")) {
        scanner.scanLocation = 1u
    }
    var hexNumber : UInt32 = 0u
    /*Type mismatch.
    Required:
    CPointer<UIntVar /* = UIntVarOf<UInt> */>?
    Found:
    UInt32 /* = UInt */
     */
    //HOW TO GET CPOINTER TO hexNumber?
    scanner.scanHexInt(hexNumber)
```

Per documentation: ([link)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/c_interop.html)

> Pointers and arrays are mapped to `CPointer<T>?.`

But how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found an answer to my question. Have to use

> memScoped

.

```
memScoped {
        var pointed : UIntVar = alloc<UIntVar>()
        scanner.scanHexInt(pointed.ptr)
        val alpha: CGFloat = 1.0
        val pointedValue = pointed.value
        val r: CGFloat = (((pointedValue and 0xFF0000) shr 16)/255.0)
        ....
}
```

The only source on the internet on this (with regards to applying it to get the pointer) here - [link](https://jonnyzzz.com/blog/2019/01/14/kn-intptr/)

[memScoped](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlinx.cinterop/mem-scoped.html)

```
inline fun <R> memScoped(block: MemScope.() -> R): R
Runs given block providing allocation of memory which will be automatically disposed at the end of this scope
```

Within it, use the extension function *alloc()* to obtain *CVariable*

```
fun <reified T : CVariable> NativePlacement.alloc(): T
```

Which then gives you access to the pointer via yet another extension function

```
val <T : CPointed> T.ptr: CPointer<T>
```

All very clear in retrospect, and clear that originally approached the problem in the wrong way, looking to get the pointer by something like `CPointer<UInt> = ...` 
Official documentation at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/c_interop.html

Comment: May be worth adding the link https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/c_interop.html to your answer, as this stuff is covered there with a few examples.